# How do I get the first pink coin on Sky-High Lifts and Leaps! (2-2)

Tags: super-mario-run

I can't figure out how to get this high pink coin. When I use the yellow lift below it, I always end up too far to the right. Even if I jump on Bullet Bill, I can only grab the rightmost coin in this set. What am I missing?

[image: mario looks sad in his bubble]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that lift goes a lot higher if you wait for it to reach apogee. The coin is very simple to get from there.

[image: Mario is cooly riding a yellow lift]